# Django3.0 : GDALException while accessing model form

Tags: python, django, django-models, geodjango, django-leaflet

I am trying to save shops with the geo locations in Django project. And I am able to save the data from admin UI but getting exception when I access the saved data.

In my django app (shop) I have following **models.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.PointField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I have installed django-leaflet **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'leaflet',
    'shops'
]
```

**admin.py** looks like this

```
#from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from .models import Shop
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin


class ShopAdmin(LeafletGeoAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'location')

admin.site.register(Shop, ShopAdmin)
```

From admin UI I am able to create shop but when I try to open any shop to view saved data I see following exception

[image]

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/shops/shop/16/change/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.7.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'leaflet',
 'shops']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 19
   OGR failure.
   9 :             {% for field in line %}
   10 :                 <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
   11 :                     {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
   12 :                     {% if field.is_checkbox %}
   13 :                         {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
   14 :                     {% else %}
   15 :                         {{ field.label_tag }}
   16 :                         {% if field.is_readonly %}
   17 :                             <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
   18 :                         {% else %}
   19 :                              {{ field.field }} 
   20 :                         {% endif %}
   21 :                     {% endif %}
   22 :                     {% if field.field.help_text %}
   23 :                         <div class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
   24 :                     {% endif %}
   25 :                 </div>
   26 :             {% endfor %}
   27 :         </div>
   28 :     {% endfor %}
   29 : </fieldset>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 992, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 971, in render_value_in_context
    value = str(value)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 373, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 33, in __str__
    return self.as_widget()
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 96, in as_widget
    renderer=self.form.renderer,
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 241, in render
    context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
  File "f:\workspaces\django\env\src\django-leaflet\leaflet\forms\widgets.py", line 78, in get_context
    context = super(LeafletWidget, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\widgets.py", line 67, in get_context
    'serialized': self.serialize(value),
  File "f:\workspaces\django\env\src\django-leaflet\leaflet\forms\widgets.py", line 40, in serialize
    return value.geojson if value else ''
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py", line 387, in json
    return self.ogr.json
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py", line 429, in ogr
    return gdal.OGRGeometry(self._ogr_ptr(), self.srs)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py", line 436, in srs
    return gdal.SpatialReference(self.srid)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\srs.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.import_epsg(srs_input)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\srs.py", line 277, in import_epsg
    capi.from_epsg(self.ptr, epsg)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\errcheck.py", line 117, in check_errcode
    check_err(result, cpl=cpl)
  File "F:\workspaces\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\error.py", line 59, in check_err
    raise e(msg)

Exception Type: GDALException at /admin/shops/shop/16/change/
Exception Value: OGR failure.
```

But When I change My **admin.py** with following I see the map but ugly view

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from .models import Shop
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin

class ShopAdmin(admin.GeoModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'location')

admin.site.register(Shop, ShopAdmin)
```

[image]

Comment: You have miss-configured gdal, probably environment variable GDAL_DATA,
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows

Comment: @iklinac Thanks for reply but when I use ````class ShopAdmin(admin.GeoModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'location')```` to register mt shop model it works but I want to use leaflet just because it shows better map view.

Comment: Hey, have you got any solution on this? I have the exact same issue with yours.

Comment: Hello @Scorpioooooon21 I don't recall exactly but it seems python version issue. and I did re install the GDAL libs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. Check your GDAL version with

```
gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28
```

Support for GDAL 3.x has just been added to django but has not yet been released as of 5/13/2020: [look here](https://github.com/django/django/commit/58f1b07e49a98bb391c9e38b91f078ab2c302703)

Probably, if you for testing purposes only (!) switch lat and long in your input to `GEOSGeometry`, it will work again. `AxisOrder` and `AxisMappingStrategy` is something new in the mentioned fix.